# Yii GridView Columns returning (not set)

Tags: php, database, yii2

I am using the Yii php framework. My goal is simple, I wish to display the following data: P_id, Autor, Anio, Titulo, Resumen. I have a modal class named ScientificProduction.

This is my code for the file:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "scientific_production".
 *
 * @property int $SP_id
 * @property int $User_id
 * @property int $P_id
 * @property string $Titulo
 */
class ScientificProduction extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'scientific_production';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['User_id', 'P_id', 'Titulo'], 'required'],
            [['User_id', 'P_id'], 'integer'],
            [['Titulo'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ];
    }

       // Define relacion con libros table
       public function getLibro()
       {
           return $this->hasOne(Libros::class, ['Libro_id' => 'P_id']);
       }
   
       // Define relacion con cap_libros table
       public function getCapLibro()
       {
           return $this->hasOne(CapLibros::class, ['Cap_id' => 'P_id']);
       }
   
       // Define relacion con articulos table
       public function getArticulo()
       {
           return $this->hasOne(Articulos::class, ['Articulos_id' => 'P_id']);
       }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'SP_id' => 'Sp ID',
            'User_id' => 'User ID',
            'P_id' => 'P ID',
            'Titulo' => 'Titulo',
        ];
    }
}
```

Now, in my controller class I declare an ActiveDataProvider  to pass it the necessary query. For this I declare it in my actionIndex function so I can render my view file index.

My code for actionIndex is this:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $provider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => ScientificProduction::find()
                ->select([
                    'scientific_production.P_id',
                    'COALESCE(libros.Autor, cap_libros.Autores_capitulo, articulos.Autor) AS Autor',
                    'COALESCE(libros.Anio, cap_libros.Anio, articulos.Anio) AS Anio',
                    'COALESCE(libros.Titulo, cap_libros.Titulo_capitulo, articulos.Titulo) AS Titulo',
                    'COALESCE(libros.Resumen, cap_libros.Resumen, articulos.Resumen) AS Resumen'
                ])
                ->leftJoin('libros', 'scientific_production.P_id = libros.Libro_id')
                ->leftJoin('cap_libros', 'scientific_production.P_id = cap_libros.Cap_id')
                ->leftJoin('articulos', 'scientific_production.P_id = articulos.Articulos_id'),
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 10, // Adjust page size as needed
            ],
            'sort' => [
                'attributes' => [
                    'P_id',
                    'Autor',
                    'Anio',
                    'Titulo',
                    'Resumen',
                ],
            ],
        ]);

        // returns an array of Post objects
        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $provider,
         ]);
    }
```

My code for the view file is this:

```
<?php
   use yii\grid\GridView;
   
   echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' =>[
         [            
             // you may configure additional properties here
             'attribute' => 'P_id',
             'headerOptions'=>[ 'style'=>'background-color:#691C32;' ]
         ],
         [            
            // you may configure additional properties here
            'attribute' => 'Autor',
            'headerOptions'=>[ 'style'=>'background-color:#691C32' ]
        ],
        [            
         // you may configure additional properties here
         'attribute' => 'Anio',
         'label' =>'Año',
         'headerOptions'=>[ 'style'=>'background-color:#691C32' ]
         ],
         [            
            // you may configure additional properties here
            'attribute' => 'Titulo',
            'headerOptions'=>[ 'style'=>'background-color:#691C32' ]
        ],
        [            
         // you may configure additional properties here
         'attribute' => 'Resumen',
         'headerOptions'=>[ 'style'=>'background-color:#691C32' ]
         ],
      ],
     ]);

?>
```

What do I expect, a grid table with the data for P_id, Autor, Anio, Titulo and Resumen.

What do I get, the values (not set) for my columns Autor, Anio and Resumen.

I do a join with three other tables, said tables have one item register. I tried debbuging the sql statement using the sql generated by yii:

```
echo $dataProvider->query->createCommand()->sql;
```

This command generated a valid sql statement that I executed in my database and got the data I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `yii\db\ActiveQuery` like this:

```php
'query' => ScientificProduction::find()
    ->select([
        // ...
    ])
    // ...
```

This is what actually happens:

1. The query is executed and data are retrieved from DB.
2. `ScientificProduction` model instance is created for each unique row returned by query.
3. Model instances are populated with data from query.

By default, the `ScientificProduction` model only "knows" about fields that matches columns in `scientific_production` DB table. When the models are populated in step 3, only "known" fields are populated with data, rest is ignored.

Then the `yii\grid\GridView` receive those models from `yii\data\ActiveDataProvider` and it's working with them. It's not working with SQL results directly. That's why fields like `P_id` and `Titulo` are fine, because they exists in `scientific_production` table, but others appear empty.

To fix it you have two options.

**1. Force `ActiveQuery` to return result as array**

When creating the query you can tell it that you don't want to create instances of `ScientificProduction` model. By calling `asArray()` method you can force `ActiveQuery` to skip steps 2 and 3 and return data from DB as array as they came from DB.

You need to simply add `asArray()` method call to the chain of methods when you are creating your query.

```php
'query' => ScientificProduction::find()
    ->select([
        // ...
    ])->asArray()
    // ...
```

**2. Create properties for calculated fields in model**

If you prepare properties for calculated fields in model they will be populated with data during step 3. For example like this:

```php
class ScientificProduction extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $Autor;
    public $Anio;
    public $Resumen;

    // ... rest of your model ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought the missing properties might be the issue. I originally got my data  through an ArrayDataProvider and it displayed exactly what I wanted, but since I wanted to include a sort and search option it seemed like my best option was to use ActiveDataProvider.